# Two project's, one compiles, the other gets error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist

Tags: javac

I know this is a common question, however my situation is a little different. I have two projects, the first doesn't use beans, the second does.

So when deploying the first project using: **ant deploy-web** it works, compiles no problem
When deploying the second project using: **ant deploy-ear** I get: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist

Any ideas?

Comment: Well it sounds like your second project doesn't have a reference to `servlet.jar` - but you haven't really given us enough information...

Comment: Where would I look for such a 'reference'? The file (class) causing the error in the second project is exactly the same in both projects.

Comment: Happy to provide more information, what do you need to know? For other projects my system is working (ant, JBoss 5.1, etc etc). My only issue appears to be compiling this project

Comment: This is solved. I looked through the build.xml and found a problem. Now compiles. Thanks Jon.